# CMake Error: CMake can not determine linker language for target: myapp

Tags: c++, cmake

I am trying to compile vMime by cmake, but I am getting error above, 
I am using graphical interface of cmake and my makefiles.txt is below. It configures properly but do not generate

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
PROJECT(CXX)#vmime
enable_language(CXX)
set(VerifyCXX VerifyCXX.cxx)
add_definitions(-DVERIFY_CXX)
set_target_properties(${TARGET} PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE Cxx)
add_executable(myapp vmime)
install(TARGETS myapp DESTINATION bin)
```

Help will be highly appreciated as I am stuck at point for couple of days.

Comment: What version of `cmake` do you have? It appears to me as if you have 2.8 or less installed, but the [current version seems to be 3.2.3](http://www.cmake.org/download/). If so, can you please upgrade to the newer version?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

CMake probably can not determine linker language for target `myapp`, because the target does not contain any source files with recognized extensions.

```
add_executable(myapp vmime)
```

should be probably replaced by

```
add_executable(myapp ${VerifyCXX})
```

Also this command

```
set_target_properties(${TARGET} PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE Cxx)
```

cannot be succesfull, because `${TARGET}` is used-before-set. You should call it after `add_executable`

```
set_target_properties(myapp PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)
```

Note that usually it is not needed at all.

Comment: Thankx, that was really useful .

Answer (score 3):

For others' benefit, make sure you did not overlook an earlier error such as:

> ```
> Cannot find source file:
>
>     MyFirstSourceFile.cpp
> ```

Another way to cause CMake to give you the error, "CMake Error: CMake can not determine linker language for target: myapp", is if you mistakenly point it exclusively at sources that do not exist.

For instance: I'm moving files from one directory to another and had the pre-move files with the post-move paths in my CMakeLists.txt.  My output window is not very tall and I focused too soon on the "can not determine linker language" error!

Answer (score 0):

I use clion IDE based on cmake, my source files named *.cc

```
project(server)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -pthread")
file(GLOB SRC_FILE "main.cc" "listenfd.cc" "socket_util.cc"
    "timers.cc" "network.cc" "main_event.cc")
add_executable(server ${server})
set_target_properties(server PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)
```

after I change

```
add_executable(server ${server}) to 
add_executable(server "main.cc")
```

then I solved it, I really don't know why?
after experiment I found when use file(GLOB ....) like file(GLOB "src/main.cc") I must specify the relative path, then it works.