# How to properly add sub-folders on a CMAKE project without receiving a linker error

Tags: c++11, cmake

I have some issue with including sub-folders on a `CMAKE` project.
Below in short the summary of the `CMAKE` tree that I have. The first layer works ok, but the second layer does not work properly throwing a `linker error`:

**ERROR:**

> CMake Error at src/ROSTemplatesMsgs/CMakeLists.txt:17
> (add_executable):   Cannot find source file:
>
> ```
> actionlib_msgs/goalID/dbGoalID.cpp
> ```
>
> Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm
> .hpp   .hxx .in .txx
>
> CMake Error: CMake can not determine linker language for target:
> goalID CMake Error: Cannot determine link language for target
> "goalID". Generating done

Project tree is shown below:

```
.
+-- Project-DriveAll[master]
+-- CMakeLists.txt
+-- src
|   +-- projectA
|   +-- projectB
|   +-- ROSTemplatesMsgs
|       +-- CMakeLists.txt
|       +-- main
|           +-- geometry_msgs.h
|           +-- main.cpp
|           +-- pointField.h
|           +-- ros_headers.h
|       +-- src
|           +-- actionlib_msgs
|               +-- goalID
|                   +-- dbGoalID.cpp
|                   +-- dbGoalID.h
|                   +-- goalIDItem.cpp
|                   +-- goalIDItem.h
|               +-- goalStatus
|                   +-- dbGoalStatus.cpp
|                   +-- dbGoalStatus.h
|                   +-- goalStatusItem.cpp
|                   +-- goalStatusItem.h
|           +-- sensor_msgs
|               +-- laserscan
|               ........
```

For a better visualization see also this:

[image: viz]

so the **root file** is below and this works well:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/Modules/")

set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib)
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
set(INCLUDE_OUTPUT_PATH ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/include)

set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -std=gnu99 -g") 
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -g")

project(Project-DriveAll)
add_subdirectory(src/projectA)
add_subdirectory(src/projectB)
add_subdirectory(src/ROSTemplatesMsgs)
```

However, below is the `CMakeLists.txt` under the project `src/ROSTemplatesMsgs` that is not compiling properly:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.1)
project(ROSTemplatesMsgs)
find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)

set (OpenCV_DIR /home/to/opencv/build)
set (BOOST_LIBRARYDIR /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu)

find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS system thread filesystem REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5PrintSupport REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core Quick Sql)

include(CheckCXXCompilerFlag)
CHECK_CXX_COMPILER_FLAG("-std=c++11" COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX11)
CHECK_CXX_COMPILER_FLAG("-std=c++0x" COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX0X)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES( ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR} )
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${Qt5Widgets_INCLUDE_DIRS})

file(GLOB SRCS
    "src/*.h"
    "src/*.cpp"
    "src/*.hpp"

    "src/actionlib_msgs/goalID/dbGoalID.cpp"
    "src/actionlib_msgs/goalID/dbGoalID.h"
    "src/actionlib_msgs/goalID/dbGoalIDItem.cpp"
    "src/actionlib_msgs/goalID/dbGoalIDItem.h"

    "src/actionlib_msgs/goalStatusArray/dbGoalStatusArray.cpp"
    "src/actionlib_msgs/goalStatusArray/dbGoalStatusArray.h"
    "src/actionlib_msgs/goalStatusArray/goalStatusArrayItem.cpp"
    "src/actionlib_msgs/goalStatusArray/goalStatusArrayItem.h"


    "src/sensor_msgs/laserscan/*.h"
    "src/sensor_msgs/laserscan/*.cpp"
    "src/sensor_msgs/laserscan/*.hpp"

    "src/visualization_msgs/marker/*.h"
    "src/visualization_msgs/marker/*.cpp"
    "src/visualization_msgs/marker/*.hpp"

    "src/visualization_msgs/markerarray/*.h"
    "src/visualization_msgs/markerarray/*.cpp"
    "src/visualization_msgs/markerarray/*.hpp"

    "src/sensor_msgs/pointcloud2/*.h"
    "src/sensor_msgs/pointcloud2/*.cpp"
    "src/sensor_msgs/pointcloud2/*.hpp"

    "src/sensor_msgs/pointcloud/*.h"
    "src/sensor_msgs/pointcloud/*.cpp"
    "src/sensor_msgs/pointcloud/*.hpp"


    "main/*.h"
    "main/*.cpp"
    "main/*.hpp"
)

file(GLOB UI_SRCS
    "ui/*.h"
    "ui/*.cpp"
    "ui/*.hpp"
)

add_executable(ROSTemplatesMsgs main/main.cpp ${SRCS})
target_link_libraries (ROSTemplatesMsgs  Qt5::Widgets  ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${OpenCV_LIBS} Qt5::PrintSupport Qt5::Core Qt5::Quick Qt5::Sql)

add_library(ROSTemplatesMsgs_lib SHARED ${SRCS} ${UI_HDRS} ${UI_SRCS})
target_include_directories (ROSTemplatesMsgs_lib PUBLIC "src/actionlib_msgs/" )
target_include_directories (ROSTemplatesMsgs_lib PUBLIC "src/sensor_msgs/" )
target_link_libraries (ROSTemplatesMsgs_lib Qt5::Widgets  ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${OpenCV_LIBS} Qt5::PrintSupport Qt5::Core Qt5::Quick Qt5::Sql)
```

I consulted a lot of resources such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31130612/cmake-error-cmake-can-not-determine-linker-language-for-target-myapp) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16655705/cmake-cannot-determine-linker-language-for-target) however in my case I am not using the `TARGET` option as not always suggested in the `CMAKE` documentation.
However I tried also to [set_target_properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61235133/cmake-can-not-determine-linker-language-for-target-c) as suggested in this post but nothing changed.
I went through [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58791470/cmake-can-not-determine-linker-language-for-target-c-language) but wasn't useful to find out what the problem was.

I also tried to [add_subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42744315/cmake-with-subdirectories) as advised on this post in the following way but that also didn't work:

```
add_subdirectory(src/actionlib_msgs)
add_subdirectory(src/sensor_msgs)
```

Another source I counsulted was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42744315/cmake-with-subdirectories) and it actually helped understand the different use if dealing with a complex project and another that is not. My project has other subprojects as shown at the beginning of the question with multiple `CMakeLists.txt` but the project `ROSTemplatesMsgs` is the one that has multiple subfolders and that is complicating the tree.

The root has the `add_subdirectory()` command and that is working well in fact.
ProjectA and ProjectB have their own `CMakeLists.txt` and no problem (but they also don't have multiple subfolders).
When it comes to the last project (the one with subfolders) something does not work properly and I am running out of ideas.

**EDITS**

Additional information after building the project can be seen in the terminal error below:

> In file included from
> /home/build-ultrasound_mapper-Desktop_Qt_5_12_2_GCC_64bit-Debug/src/ROSTemplatesMsgs/ROSTemplatesMsgs_autogen/mocs_compilation.cpp:3:0:
> /home/build-ultrasound_mapper-Desktop_Qt_5_12_2_GCC_64bit-Debug/src/ROSTemplatesMsgs/ROSTemplatesMsgs_autogen/WKFP3Z6SYI/moc_dbGoalStatus.cpp:57:6:
> error: ‘dbGoalStatus’ has not been declared  void
> dbGoalStatus::qt_static_metacall(QObject *_o, QMetaObject::Call _c,
> int _id, void **_a)

> /home/build-ultrasound_mapper-Desktop_Qt_5_12_2_GCC_64bit-Debug/src/ROSTemplatesMsgs/ROSTemplatesMsgs_autogen/WKFP3Z6SYI/moc_dbGoalStatus.cpp:65:38:
> error: ‘dbGoalStatus’ has not been declared  QT_INIT_METAOBJECT const
> QMetaObject dbGoalStatus::staticMetaObject = { {
> ^~~~~~~~~~~~

> /home/labrat/build-ultrasound_mapper-Desktop_Qt_5_12_2_GCC_64bit-Debug/src/ROSTemplatesMsgs/ROSTemplatesMsgs_autogen/WKFP3Z6SYI/moc_dbGoalStatus.cpp:75:20:
> error: ‘dbGoalStatus’ has not been declared  const QMetaObject
> *dbGoalStatus::metaObject() const
> ^~~~~~~~~~~~

> /home/build-ultrasound_mapper-Desktop_Qt_5_12_2_GCC_64bit-Debug/src/ROSTemplatesMsgs/ROSTemplatesMsgs_autogen/WKFP3Z6SYI/moc_dbGoalStatus.cpp:75:47:
> error: non-member function ‘const QMetaObject* metaObject()’ cannot
> have cv-qualifier  const QMetaObject *dbGoalStatus::metaObject() const
> ^~~~~

which seems to point to a linker error.

Comment: When you say that "the first layer works ok", do you mean that you can build from the root project, but not from the `ROSTemplatesMsgs`?

Comment: The path in the error message - `actionlib_msgs/goalID/dbGoalID.cpp` - doesn't correspond to the path in the code `src/actionlib_msgs/goalID/dbGoalID.cpp`. Smells like you have some **other** project, or something wrong with the cache.

Comment: @JonasVautherin, thanks for stopping by and reading. Yes the root project works and cmake parses all the files. However when I try to build the project it stops right at the `ROSTemplatesMsgs` project, specifically when trying to build the subfolders. Which makes me think that I have something missing or not right.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, thanks for stopping by and reading, for the cache I erased it and rebuilt the project several times, I cleaned it and and run cmake from zero before rebuilding it. The project parses correctly but when it comes to build it it stops right at the ``ROSTemplatesMsgs` project that has the subfolders. Also I didn't totally understood what you mean of the path. Can you be a bit more clear please :) ?

Comment: If that is useful I added more detail on the error at terminal, you can see the **EDITS** in the question. Thank you guys for reading I appreciate your time.

Comment: Maybe you think I should add a `CMakeLists.txt` under each folder? Or maybe that is excessive? I think it is excessive but I am running out of ideas..

Comment: No that's not necessary. What I don't get is if it fails when you run cmake from the root, or if you do something like `cd src/ROSTemplatesMsgs` and try to run cmake from there. Because you declare it as its own project (`project(ROSTemplatesMsgs)`), so I guess you may want to build it standalone. What is the command you run, and from where?

Comment: Yes I run it from the root. I am using `Qt5` as IDE and I am just pushing the build button which build the whole project so it will build "ProjectA", "ProjectB" and "ROSTemplatesMsgs". Each project has its own `CMakeLists.txt`. All other projects don't have subfolders. The "ROSTemplatesMsgs" one is the one with subfolders, which means that the `MakeLists.txt` referred to `ROSTemplatesMsgs` is not properly written, but I don't see what is wrong with that.

Comment: The error message started with `CMake Error` is the error emitted by **CMake**. Not sure why you refer to it as a "linker error": this is a **configuration** error, which comes before **building** the project, when files are compiled and linked. BTW, the location noted in that error - `src/ROSTemplatesMsgs/CMakeLists.txt:17 (add_executable)` - definitely does NOT corresponds to line `add_executable(ROSTemplatesMsgs main/main.cpp ${SRCS})` in the `CMakeLists.txt` which you show. Please, post only error messages **relevant** to the code you show in the post.

Comment: And please, do not use *blockquote* formatting for the error messages: this formatting doesn't preserves newlines, so messages become harder to read. Use **code** formatting instead.